# the trait bound `std::io::Write + 'static: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied, when passing closure

Tags: rust, traits, higher-order-functions

I am trying to get rid of some code duplication in my program and I decided to go with a function that will take a closure of type `Fn() -> Result<io::Write>` that will supply for me an output stream when I ask for it.

So here is this function:

```
fn dowload_body<F>(/* some params ommited */ write_supplier: F) -> Result<()>
  where F: Fn() -> Result<Write> {
  if ... {
    let mut destination = try!(write_supplier());
    // use this stream
  }
}
```

And I want to use it for example like this:

```
let destination_path = Path::new("some path");
let result = Self::dowload_body(|| try_str!(OpenOptions::new().append(true).open(destination_path)));
```

I am getting following error:

```
src/http.rs:105:3: 121:4 error: the trait bound `std::io::Write + 'static: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied [E0277]
src/http.rs:105   fn dowload_body<F>(write_supplier: F) -> Result<()>
                  ^
```

I am new to rust and had no luck finding a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put an unsized variable (a trait) directly in a Result. Perhaps you mean this?

```
fn dowload_body<F, W: Write>(write_supplier: F) -> Result<()>
//                 ^
  where F: Fn() -> Result<W> 
//                        ^ create a template for the trait.
{
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. So I understand that I always have to return a concrete type, which trait ofc is not, so I need to build a template for any concrete type `W` that has implementation of `Write` trait. Am I right?

Comment: @Łukasz Right. Alternatively you could use a trait object e.g. `Box<Write>`, but that would require dynamic dispatch (more indirection)